# Raspberry Pi as Time Machine

Tags: network, backup, time-machine

Is it possible to setup a Raspberry Pi with a USB HD to act as a Time Machine?

Comment: I do not have a Raspberry Pi to test with and why I'm leaving this as a comment. From what I've read in the following two links as well as other articles on the Internet, I'd have to say... Yes, you can setup and use a disk connected to a Raspberry Pi for a Time Machine Backup. Have a look at: [Backup disks you can use with Time Machine](https://support.apple.com/HT202784) & [How to Use a Raspberry Pi as a Networked Time Machine Drive For Your Mac](https://www.howtogeek.com/276468/how-to-use-a-raspberry-pi-as-a-networked-time-machine-drive-for-your-mac/)

Comment: Somewhat embarrassingly, I just found this after 1 minute of googling: https://www.jannikarndt.de/blog/2018/01/how_to_use_a_raspberry_pi_for_your_time_machine_backups/ Posted the question here as when I searched previously I found nothing useful on the inter webs. Things appear to have changed!

Comment: I'm sorry, but I think that solution you've linked to is ridiculous! I mean why go to all of that trouble, when all you really need to do is connect the USB drive directly to your Mac?

Comment: So I don’t have to drag the HD around with me. Did you kiss the point of the question and the article?

Comment: I don't think that Raspberry can work as Time Machine ( for backup purposes ), MacOS uses hard link to directory and AFAIK these are not supported on any raspberry FS. Do it at your own risk. No issues when using Raspberry as File Server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answered my question perfectly:

https://www.jannikarndt.de/blog/2018/01/how_to_use_a_raspberry_pi_for_your_time_machine_backups/